# Find if Array Contains 5 consecutive Numbers with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a sorted Array that contains numbers.  I want to be able to check if this Array(or similar Array), contains 5 numbers in consecutive order.

NOTE: Array may contain duplicate and double digit numbers.

I am trying this, but failing epically.

```
var array = [1,3,5,7,7,8,9,10,11]
var current = null;
var cnt = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] != current) {
        if (cnt > 4) {
            return true;
        }
        current = array[i];
        cnt = 1;
    } else {
        cnt++;
    }

}
if (cnt > 4) {
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: means can you give a sample input and expected answer.

Comment: What have you tried? My approach to this would be something along the lines of: iterate through the array, store the current value, if the next value is the same as the current, increment a counter. If they are different, set the counter back to 0.

Comment: find the content in this article :http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-array-elements-are-consecutive/

Comment: is this defined inside a function? Not sure where `return true` would go, or how you would see the result. Also, `cnt` will only increase once, when it hits the two `7`s

Comment: By "consecutive", what do you mean? In your sample data, the numbers or not "consecutive", they are merely monotonically increasing. Are duplicates counted in the five in a row, or skipped for counting purposes?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`cnt` will only increase once, when it hits the two 7s.

Put the incrementing line in the truthy condition, and the reset line in the else statement.

```js
// Put into a function for testing.
function foo() {
  var array = [1, 3, 5, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
  var current = null;
  var cnt = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // Also need to make sure the next array item is a consecutive increase.
    if (array[i] != current && array[i] === array[i-1] + 1) {
      if (cnt > 4) {
        return true;
      }

      current = array[i];
      cnt++;
    } else {
      cnt = 1;
    }
  }

  if (cnt > 4) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

// Call function.
alert(foo());
```

Answer (score 3):

An iterative, straightforward approach would be:

```
var should_be_true = [1,3,5,7,7,8,9,10,11];
var should_be_false = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17];

var testArray = function(array) {
    var conseq = 1;
    for (var idx = 1; idx < array.length ; idx++) {
        if (array[idx] == array[idx-1] + 1)
            conseq++;
        else
            conseq = 1;
        if (conseq == 5)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(testArray(should_be_true)); //true
console.log(testArray(should_be_false)); //false
```

But for bonus fun, here's one variation on a functional approach, returning the position where the sequence starts, or -1 if no sufficiently long sequence exists:

```
should_be_true.map(function(curr,idx,arr) {
    return (curr == arr[idx-1] +1) ? 1 : 0;
}).join('').search(/1{4}/);
```

Answer (score 3):

A functional approach would be

```
function fiveInARow(array) {

  // compare if one element is greater than or equal to the previous one
  function compare(elt, i, arr) { return !i || elt >= arr[i-1]; });

  // check if at a given position, every one of the last five comparisons is true
  function check (_, i, greaters) { 
    return i >= 4 && greaters.slice(i-4, i) . every(Boolean);                         
  }

  return array . map(compare) . some(check);
}
```

The logic here is to first create an array of booleans using `map`, showing whether each element is greater than or equal to the previous. That yields an array such as `[true, true, true, false, true]`.

The `some` part asks, for any element, is it the case that that element and every one of the preceding four elements are true? If so, it returns `true`.

#### Recursive solution

A recursive solution might be a bit easier to read.

```
function fiveInARow(array) {

  return function _five(array, prev, n) {
    if (n >= 5)        return true;
    if (!array.length) return false;

    var next = array.shift();
    return _five(array, next, next === prev ? n : next >= prev ? n+1 : 0);
  }(array, -999999, 5);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [1,3,5,7,7,8,9,10,11];
var cons=false;
var count=0;
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(array[i]+1==array[i+1]){
        count++;
    }
    else{
        count=0;
    }
    if(count==4){
        cons=true;
    }
}
if(cons){
    //do what you want with it
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/knzfxkdh/)**

a more elegant way would be to define this whole thing in a function as below:

```
function checkCons(array){
    var cons=false;
    var count=0;
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i]+1==array[i+1]){
            count++;
        }
        else{
            count=0;
        }
        if(count==4){
            cons=true;
        }
    }
    return cons;
}
```

and then using it like this:

```
var array = [1,3,5,7,7,8,9,10,11];
if(checkCons(array)){
    //do what you want with it
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/knzfxkdh/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
   function fiveStraight() {
       var array = [1, 3, 5, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12];
       var prev = array[0];
       var numberOfStraight = 1;

       for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
           numberOfStraight = array[i] === prev + 1 ? numberOfStraight + 1 : 1;
           prev = array[i];
           if (numberOfStraight === 5) return true;
       }

       return false;
   }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0nzaykt4/).

Comment: Would it be more efficient to check 5+ ahead of each index before doing consecutive order check?

Comment: I don't think so.
The worst case = go through the whole array. The best case is if the streak falls on the first number. I start from the beginning and go towards the end. If I find a streak I return true. If not and I got to the end I return false. I don't see how you can improve that approach.

Comment: Actually, that's an interesting question. You CAN roughly double the efficiency of this search by only reading every second position (incrementing your index by 2 instead of 1). If the two values differ by 2, go back and check the one in between. You'll avoid some number of unnecessary reads that way...n/2 in the case where no sequence was present.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found out to be the most straight forwards approach. Both descending and ascending values count as consecutive (if that's not your case, then fiddle with the `Math.abs()` call).

```
function consecutiveValuesCount(array) {
    // sort the values if not pre-sorted
    var sortedValues = array.sort();

    // the result variable / how many consecutive numbers did we find?
    // there's always atleast 1 consecutive digit ...
    var count = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < sortedValues.length - 1; i++) {
        // both descending and ascending orders count as we are using Math.abs()
        if (Math.abs(sortedValues[i] - sortedValues[i+1]) == 1) {
          ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

---

```
//input
var array = [1,2,4,5,3];
// output
5
```

Answer (score 0):

with this code you can find the highest number of consecutives for a given number or find the highest number of consecutives in general

```
var findMaxConsecutiveOnes = function (arr, number) {
   //check for boundries
   if(!number || !arr.length) return;

  // maximum number of consectuives
  let max = 0;

  // count homy many consecutives before it ends (why it's 1 ? because a lonely number is still counted)
  let counter = 1;

  // you can ignore the next 2 variable if you want to use for loop instead of while
  let length = arr.length;
  let i = 1; // counting from index 1 because we are checking against index-1
  while (i < length) {

    if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {

      // boom, we have a consecutive, count it now
      counter++;
    } else {

      // rest to 1
      counter = 1;
    }

    // always update the max variable to the new max value
    max = Math.max(counter, max);

    //for the sake of iteration
    i++;
  }
  return max== number;
};
console.log(findMaxConsecutiveOnes([5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
```

Comment: Sorry, it was my first answer :D gonna edit it